# Redux/ES6 - Object literal shorthand syntax for not working in connect function as expected

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

While trying to dispatch an action `myAction` it was failing till I rearranged es6 code that syntactically appears to be the same.

**It is most likely me not getting something about es6 object literal shorthand, or what the `connect` function is doing under the hood.**

Ex 1 - Not Working

`myAction` not being interpreted correctly as shorthand for a return of an object literal where key and value name match.

```
var mapDispatchToProps = () => ({myAction});

MyComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps 
)(MyComponent);
```

Ex 2 - Working

Once I added the shorthand syntax for `myAction` into in the `connect` function directly it worked as expected.

```
MyComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {myObject}
)(MyComponent);
```

**Question:**

The first case I expected the function to return an object literal identical to the second. Why is that not so.

**Update To Accompany Answer:**

The answer below is correct - if you want to see a video explaining it go here https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-using-mapdispatchtoprops-shorthand-notation

Comment: "Why is that not so." --- because a function that returns an object is not the same as the object itself.

Comment: It really depends on the function handling it and the mapDispatchToProps is a function handed to the connect method in many of Dan Abramov's examples

Comment: It is indeed (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), and it works without problems.

Comment: Ohhh the connect method handles functions and objects loosely. That's nice but tricky when reading and factoring in other new syntax im learning.

Comment: From the docs: *"If a function is passed, it will be given `dispatch`. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses `dispatch` to bind action creators in your own way.  (Tip: you may use the bindActionCreators() helper from Redux.) "*

Comment: @FelixKling is correct. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (return {someCallBack: () => dispatch({myAction})});
```

It looks like the first example is missing the `dispatch` argument and call.  Checkout the [TodoList](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) example.  You can then use `someCallBack` in your component that is passed to connect().

From the [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) docs:

> If a function is passed, it will be given dispatch. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses dispatch to bind action creators in your own way.

Comment: I believe `dispatch({myAction})` makes very little sense.

Comment: [dispatch](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) accepts an action.  I edited the answer to include more detail.  I took me a minute to get everything written.